# Dot syntax vs param passing syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax

Are only the core Ruby methods callable using object.functionName syntax? Is it possible to create methods on my own that are callable in the dot syntax fashion?

For this method:

```
def namechanger (name)

    nametochange = name
    puts "This is the name to change: #{nametochange}"

end
```

First one below works, the second does not.

```
namechanger("Steve")

"Steve".namechanger
```

I get an error on `"Steve".namechanger`

The error is:

```
rb:21:in `<main>': private method `namechanger' called for "Steve":String (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Well, the question begs *what error message*? And then **Why does it make sense**? While you *can* "open classes" in Ruby, this can also lead to lots of pollution. Perhaps you want to follow a pattern such as `Person.new("Steve").change_name("Fred")`?

Comment: Note that `obj.m` *always* means "send message `m` to the receiver `obj`" which implies that, in Ruby, the only way to make `"x".m` work is to enable `"x"`, or a parent, e.g. `String`, respond to `m`. (In some *other languages* it is possible to create overloads without changing the receiver or receivers parent(s).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add methods to the String class to achieve your desired effect; the variable "`self`" refers to the object which receives the method call.

```
class String
  def namechanger
    "This is the name to change: #{self}"
  end
end
"Steve".namechanger # => This is the name to change: Steve
```

This practice is known as [monkey patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) and should be used carefully.

Comment: Note: *should be used carefully* or (mine) *likely not here*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of monkeypatching, you could alway subclass and thus:

1. Be precise about what you think the object *really* is.
2. Gain all the methods of String

For example:

```
class PersonName < String  
  def namechanger  
    puts "This is the name to change: #{self}"  
  end  
end  

s = PersonName.new( "Iain" )  
s.namechanger

This is the name to change: Iain  
=> nil
```

Comment: I noticed you passed 'Iain' to new. But when you called namechanger on s, it still printed correct. How did new method know to send 'Iain' to def namechanger?

Comment: Because it subclasses String, it acts like a string (it's an _enhanced_ string). Think of it as, when you refer to `self` in the String class it will return the string it's holding. Hence, "Iain".

Comment: Actually, it's bad of me to over simplify that. In any class `self` refers to itself. If you put a String object in a string like "This is the name to change: ___" it will output the string. So, in this case, `self` will output "Iain".

Comment: https://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes

Comment: @Kris Although I'd disagree with some of Klabnik's reasoning (a name most certainly is a string, especially if he thinks a list is an array; and I'd expect an Array if I called `to_a`) but it's still fair to say there are pitfalls and better ways to do this (depending on need). I'd also say it's a failing of the Ruby dev team if optimisations have broken the object model but *the perfect is the enemy of the good* so I won't complain (too much;-) Thanks.

Comment: @iain I'm inclined to agree with you. It might not actually be a problem on other interpreters like JRuby, but worth knowing for CRuby.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here in the first form is a method which takes a parameter, which is very different than a method that doesn't take any parameters. Let me illustrate

`ruby
namechanger("Steve")`

Looks for a method named `namechanger` and passes a string argument to it. Straight forward. It looks up in some unknown context, probably the locals of another method which will look it up on the object that receives that method.

`ruby
"Steve".namechanger`

is a method that takes no arguments that exists on `String`. Typically these methods use the implicit `self` parameter to operate on some data.

Comment: So a method that takes parameters can NOT be called in dot syntax and only methods that take no arguments CAB be called with dot syntax, when a method takes no arguments self is used to refer to the object before the dot?

Comment: the "dot syntax" you refer to is merely the mechanism for calling a method on some object. It can be used anywhere where you define a method on some object (class or instance of a class).

Comment: These example merely define a method without parameters because the original method took a single string, and if you define that method on a string itself, then you don't need to pass it as a parameter anymore. You could of course define methods like `class String; def change_to(name); puts "Changing #{self} to #{name}; end; end`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to call `"Steve".namechanger`, you have to make `namechanger` a method of the `String` class like this:

```
class String
  def namechanger
    puts "This is the name to change: #{self}"
  end
end
```

This is generally referred to as "monkey patching" and you might want to improve your general Ruby proficiency a bit before you get into the related considerations and discussions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
class String
  def namechanger
    puts "This is the name to change: #{self}"
  end
end
```

The difference is that your first example is a method that's (basically) globally defined, which takes a string and operates on it. This code above however defines a method called "namechanger" which takes no parameters, and defines it directly on the String class. So any and all strings in your application will then have this method.

But as pst said, you should probably not dive into that style of programming until you get a little more familiar with Ruby, so that you can more easily see the upsides and downsides of doing monkeypatching like this. One of the considerations is that you probably have many strings that don't represent names, and it doesn't make a lot of sense for those strings to have a method called namechanger.

That said, if your goal is just to have a little fun with Ruby, to see what you can do, go for it, but remember to be more careful in projects that will have a longer lifespan.